# Ajaxified group of flags

Tags: 7, ajax, javascript, flags

I have a custom content type named Movie.

Every user must have 3 lists of movies :-

1) seen

2) want to see

3) watching right now

Right now i am solving these by adding three flags(seen,want to see,watching) on movie content.
That is on every movie node and teaser these 3 flags are shown.and by clicking those flags user can add that particular movie to corresponding list. 
But these 3 buttons make the look clumsy and the users are finding it not too easy to populate their list of movies.

Now i want to have a ADD button, that should appear on every movie node and teaser ,when a user hovers on the add button or clicks on it ,those 3 flags should appear, and then the user by selecting the corresponding flag, can populate his list.

And this should be ajaxified.

How can i do this??

I am using Drupal 7 and the flag module.

Please help :-)

THANX IN ADVANCE